# Negating \ifeof

Tags: macros, conditionals, plain-tex

Trying to typeset lines from a file:

```
\openin0=MyFile

\loop
  \read0to\linein
  \linein
  \ifeof0              % Fails here
\repeat
```

Clearly, I want to test for *not* \ifeof, but I don't see a boolean negation operator in Ch 20 of the TeXBook.  Can I do this in plain TeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) how about `\openin\File=MyFile\loop\unless\ifeof\File...\repeat`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends a bit what you mean by plain TeX.

As cmhughes just mentioned in comments you could use the e-TeX `unless` command to negate the expression or you could copy the LaTeX definition of `\loop` which would allow you to do

```
\openin0=MyFile

\loop
  \read0to\linein
  \linein
  \ifeof0              % Fails here
  \else
\repeat
```

so that you could work with an unextended TeX.

The plain `\loop` is

```
\def\loop#1\repeat{\def\body{#1}\iterate}
\def\iterate{\body \let\next\iterate \else\let\next\relax\fi \next}
\let\repeat=\fi
```

LaTeX uses the following definition so `\else` works.

```
\def\loop#1\repeat{\def\iterate{#1\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi}%
  \iterate \let\iterate\relax}
\let\repeat\fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David.  Copied, compiled, and ran.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

If you like theory, here is David Kastrup’s `\ifnot` macro:

```
\def\ifnot#1{#1\else\expandafter\expandafter\fi\iffalse\iftrue\fi}
```

This can be used as

```
\loop ... \ifnot{\ifeof\stream} ... \repeat
```

See [Victor Eijkhout, TUGBoat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-1/tb66eijk.pdf).